# How to connect SQl Server using katalon version 7.0.1

Tags: java, sql-server, selenium-webdriver, groovy, jira

```
public class dbtesting {

  private static Connection connection = null;

  def connection(String server, String port, String dbname, String username, String password) {
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + server + ":" + port + ";databaseName=" + dbname + ";user=" + username + ";password=" + password + ";IntegratedSecurity=true"
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url)
  }
}
```

**This is custom keyword which I am using to connect to sqlserver but its getting failed.**
at TempTestCase1580391392461.run(TempTestCase1580391392461.groovy:23)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
**7
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1745)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.(AuthenticationJNI.java:58)

What am i missing ? thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

**SQL Server Db connection for window authentication is working for me with below code**

```
def connection(String server, String port, String username, String Password, String dbname) {
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + server + ":" + port + ";databaseName=" + dbname  + ";IntegratedSecurity=true"

    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url)
```

**When we connect through window authentication no need to pass username and password.**